# Solaris 10: Disable default sendmail inboxes

Tags: solaris, sendmail, users, solaris-10

An inbox is automatically created for every UNIX user on the box, when the mail is sent to the nodename of the system.

Is there a way to disable these default inboxes?

An example of one of these inboxes is root@nodename.

It would be preferable not to remove the nodename from local-host-names.

I do have other domains set up on this sendmail server, that need to stay running.

Comment: What do you mean by disabling? Should mail to these mail boxes be discarded? Forwarded somewhere else?

Comment: Discarded, unless I say otherwise in virtusertable. Currently, the virtusertable lists all valid email addresses. If root@nodename is not in virtusertable, then it should be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [have a look here](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.gr/2009/11/configuring-sendmail-on-solaris-10.html), in order to understand how to produce a `sendmail.cf` from `sendmail.mc` and restart sendmail afterwards.

Now forget virtusertable.  We will define a class of usernames which are allowed to receive mail. All the rest will be discarded.  To do this we add the following section in `sendmail.mc`

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
C{Receive} user1 user2 user3
```

If you want to define these users in an external file, instead of directly editing your `sendmail.mc`, use an F line, instead of a C line:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
F{Receive} -o /etc/mail/receive.allow
```

This way each line in the file `/etc/mail/receive.allow` contains a username that is allowed to receive mail. The `-o` switch makes sure that sendmail will not complain if the file does not exist.

Now that the users that are allowed to receive mail are defined, we add the following lines next:

```
LOCAL_RULE_0
R${Receive}       $#OK
R${Receive} < @ $=w . > $*        $#OK
R$*        $#discard $: $1
```

Do not copy paste the above snippet of code. The left hand side of the code is tab separated from the right hand one. So type it instead.  Next follow the instructions for how to compile `sendmail.cf` from `sendmail.mc` and restart sendmail.

Each time you modify `sendmail.mc` in order to add a user, you need to reproduce `sendmail.cf` and restart sendmail. If you choose to store allowed users in an external file, each time you modify this file you need to restart sendmail (no need for a new `sendmail.cf`).